# ¿Como trabajar con archivos binarios con git/github?

Tags: git, github

Vi que subir archivos binarios al repositorio es mala practica ya que pesan mucho ¿que alternativa tengo si mi proyecto tiene imagenes y necesito subirlas?

Comment: Existe el peligro de que su pregunta conduzca a respuestas basadas en las opiniones de la gente y no en respuestas objetivas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema de los archivos binarios no es que pesen mucho, sino que no es posible hacer "diff" entre ellos, por lo que los cambios que sufran no se pueden guardar de forma eficiente, como hace `git` con los ficheros de texto en los que se guardan sólo las líneas que han cambiado. Los binarios deben volver a guardarse completos cada vez que son modificados.

Si no se modifican casi nunca, no hay ningún problema en guardarlos en el repositorio.

Otro asunto es el de si es **necesario** guardarlos. En muchos casos los archivos binarios son el resultado de compilar o ejecutar otros archivos. En ese caso no hay necesidad alguna de subirlos al repositorio, pues el usuario del mismo puede volver a crear esos archivos a partir de los fuentes o las herramientas necesarias. No parece que sea este el caso de las imágenes sin embargo.

Finalmente, el tamaño sí puede llegar a ser un problema. Github empieza a protestar si subes un archivo de más de 50MB, y directamente no te deja si son más de 100MB. De todas formas esto son límites para *archivos individuales*, no para el total del repositorio para el cual no existe límite. Dudo que tengas imágenes de 50MB, pero por si acaso, para casos de repositorios que requieran almacenar grandes ficheros recomiendan usar un servicio paralelo llamado "Git Large File Storage". Más info [aqui](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files)

Comment: La pregunta esta basada en opiniones, ayúdanos a responder preguntas basadas en el documento [ask], saludos.